# Normality of tau-statistics ($\tau_{\mu}$ and $\tau_{\tau}$) in presence of unit roots

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

The original [Dickey-Fuller (1979) paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286348#metadata_info_tab_contents), considers three regressions ($(1.1), (2.1)$ and $(2.2)$) but only two DGP ($1.1$ and $2.1$), while deriving the limiting distributions. The paper defines three of t-type statistics ($\tau, \tau_{\mu}, \tau_{\tau}$) for $\hat \rho$ one each for the three regressions:

\begin{align}
Y_t &= \rho Y_{t-1} + e_t \tag{1.1} \\
Y_t &= \mu + \rho Y_{t-1} + e_t \tag{2.1} \\
Y_t &= \mu + \beta t +\rho Y_{t-1} + e_t \tag{2.2}
\end{align}

Although this might be common knowledge for many, but I was surprised to learn that under the null hypothesis of $\rho=1$ for the regression $(2.1)$, $\tau_{\mu}$ is normally distributed **IF** $\mu \ne 0$, and so is $\tau_{\tau}$ in regression ($2.2$) **IF** $\beta \ne 0$. The relevant text part from the paper is below:

[image]

If so (please correct if I have understood this wrong), does this mean that to test the null of random walk with drift, against the alternative of stationary series with non-zero mean, $\tau_{\mu}$ can be compared with against critical values from normal distribution? Obviously, this test doesn't seem very useful as in most cases visual inspection would indicate whether there is a trend or not.

More importantly, the fact that $(2.2)$ as DGP is not considered, is the alternative hypothesis of trend-stationarity not available in any of the three types of ADF test? I am asking this because, in many applications, required test would be to check the null of random walk with drift against the alternative of trend-stationarity. However, based on above understanding, in ADF test at best we can check for unit root with quadratic trend as null against the alternative of linear trend - and even for this we only need critical values from normal distribution.